# Typescript custom properties name

Tags: typescript

I am currently faced with the following situation:

I write the typescript definition of a JS module, and the call function of this module look like this:

```
declare function module<I>(
  instance: I,
  options: module.Options
): module.Module<I>
```

And the module namespace:

```
declare namespace module {
  interface Module<I> {
    use(): any;
    after(): any;
    ready(): any;
  }

  interface Options {
    expose?: {
      use?: string;
      after?: string;
      ready?: string;
    }
  }
}
```

The expose option is used to change the method name in module.module, only, I don't know:

1) Like having a default fallback on use, after and ready names

2) Let the user specify a new name for these methods

I don't know if Typescript has that flexibility ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it has some flexibility, but not much - you can have a type with method names inferred from data, but the data must come in a form of string literals - you can't have a variable containing a desired name for a method, pass that variable to `module` function and magically get a type with that name.

And I'm not sure if it's worth the effort:

```
declare function module<I, U extends string = string, A extends string = string, R extends string = string>(
  instance: I,
  options: module.Options<U, A, R>
): module.Module<I, U, A, R>

declare namespace module {

  interface DefaultModule<I> {
    use(): any;
    after(): any;
    ready(): any;
    }

    type Module<I, U extends string, A extends string, R extends string> =
        string extends U ? DefaultModule<I> :
        string extends A ? DefaultModule<I> :
        string extends R ? DefaultModule<I> :
        // here we have specific names in U, A, R, not just strings
        { [u in U]: () => any } & { [a in A]: () => any } & { [r in U]: () => any }
        ;    

  interface Options<U extends string = string, A extends string = string, R extends string = string> {
    expose?: {
      use?: U;
      after?: A;
      ready?: R;
    }
  }
}

interface ExposeNames<U extends string, A extends string, R extends string> {
    useName: U;
    afterName: A;
    readyName: R;
}

function moduleOptions<U extends string, A extends string, R extends string>({useName, afterName, readyName}: ExposeNames<U, A, R>): module.Options<U, A, R> {
    return {
        expose: {use: useName, after: afterName, ready: readyName}
    }
}

const moduleA = module({}, {});
moduleA.use();

const moduleB = module({}, moduleOptions({ useName: 'use1', afterName: 'after1', readyName: 'ready1' }));
moduleB.use1();
```

Comment: Thank you for your sample code. Indeed, it is very clear that Typescript is not intended to handle this kind of case. I will try to refactor some things in the code to override this change of property. thank you for your help!